# Jquery event like $(window).load for partial view

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have event that fires on `window.load`

```
$(window).load(function () {...});
```

But I have logic on this page which update partial view. After this logic I also want to execute `window.load`.

How can I do this?

Document ready doens't help

Comment: Are you loading the partial via AJAX? If so use a callback function.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, thanks, this helps

Comment: There is no such event. You'll instead have to look for all things within the newly loaded content that have their own load events, and when they've all been called, then you can be sure everything has been loaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you're using jQuery's ajax to load the partial views:

First, you'll want to separate out the code that happens on both full and partial loads:

```
    function OnLoadTasks() {
    // stuff that happens on every load.
    }
    $(window).load(function () {
        OnLoadTasks();
        // Other stuff that only happens on full load, if any
    });
```

Then you can easily call that function again later:

```
$.ajax(...)
.done(function(r) {
    // Do whatever tasks need to be done to load the data
    OnLoadTasks();
});
```

$.ajax() could also be one of the shortcuts, like $.get() or $.load()